# AddRange/concat functionality inside a lambda Select expression

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, addrange

```
class Foo
{
    int PrimaryItem;
    bool HasOtherItems;
    IEnumerable<int> OtherItems;
}

List<Foo> fooList;
```

How do I get a list of all item ids referenced inside `fooList`?

```
var items = fooList
             .Select(
              /*
                f => f.PrimaryItem;
                if (f.HasOtherItems)
                    AddRange(f => f.OtherItems)
              */  
              ).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` and have it return a concatenated list of the `PrimaryItem` and `OtherItems` (if they are present):

```
var result = fooList
    .SelectMany(f => (new[] { f.PrimaryItem })
        .Concat(f.HasOtherItems ? f.OtherItems : new int[] { }))
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation:

```
var items = fooList.Select(i => i.PrimaryItem).Union(
      fooList.Where(foo => foo.HasOtherItems).SelectMany(foo => foo.OtherItems));
```

This takes the set of `PrimaryItem`, and (where `HasOtherItems` is set) concatenates the combined set of `OtherItems`. The `Union` ensures distinct.